# How to replace a part of formula and modify it using excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, replace, find

Let's say I have a column in excel where many cells are populated with values from sheets and a formula. For example, a cell has '82'!G7*2*F3^2*$F$6. (where 82 is the name of the sheet values are coming from. I want to write a for or loop that goes through all the cells and change all the 82s to something else, 85 for example. and also the $F$s to $H$.

What's the code to find these certain parts to then be able to replace them within the formula or whatever it is that is in a cell?

Comment: Have you tried recording the Find & Replace action performed directly on the worksheet? (Ctrl+H)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. The macro seems to run, but no changes. In fact it does but I cannot control it.  I could write Columns("Z:Z").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="A", Replacement:="B", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False and it works but it I change "A" and "B" to something like Range("X1").Value it does not anymore. I also forgot to mention that I want the string that is to be found, and its replacement to be input parameters.

Answer (score 2):

For example looping through column A using i as the counter:

```
Cells(i,1).Formula = Replace(Cells(i,1).Formula,"82","85")
Cells(i,1).Formula = Replace(Cells(i,1).Formula,"$F$","$H$")
```

Comment: Thanks, this one finally worked. Still it wouldn't work if I used column numbers. I had to change the number to the name of the column.